# migrating byte csv to blob storage

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, blob

Currently I have table stores 2 pdf files(converted to byte), each of file are approximatly 50kb. The db is on Azure. It seems it's a bad practice.
So, I've decided to move those bytes to blob somehow. But I have no idea where to start.

Do I need to somehow transfer all the stored data to the blob first. if yes, then advise some way (article, or personal experience)

then should I need to rewrite the logic for retriving a file from a blob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all, to interact with blob storage you will need a the [Azure.Storage.Blobs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs) nuget package.
- To interact with the blob storage, you will need a connection string for authentication. This will be available in the `Access Keys`  tab in the portal. Other options for auth such as azure ad and sas tokens are also available

[image]

- Now you will need a `BlobServiceClient`  , `BlobContainerClient` and a `BlobClient`. All three of them basically represent the blob storage, container in which the blobs will be stored and blob itself.

code:

```
// Refrence to blob storage
        BlobServiceClient client = new BlobServiceClient("<Your Connection String >");
        
//Refrence to Container
        BlobContainerClient container = client.GetBlobContainerClient("< Name of Your Container>");

// Here I am asuming you already have a container 

// If not it can be created in the portal under the CONTAINERS tab

// Make sure that the PUBLIC ACCESS LEVEL is set to CONTAINER

// Reference to blob

        BlobClient blob = container.GetBlobClient("< Name Of the BLob>");
```

Now using the `BlobClient`, we can connect to blob storage and upload/download files.

- Since your files are in byte array you can upload that also in the blob storage using `uploadAsync` method and `MemoryStream`

code:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytearray, false))
        {
            await blob.UploadAsync(ms);
        }
```

- Here we are converting byte array and adding that to blob storage .
- Here I have created a console app which will upload a byte array in blob storage.

code :

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using static System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSType;


using System;

class Program
{

    
    static public async Task Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        string conn = "";
       
        BlobServiceClient client = new BlobServiceClient(conn);
    
        BlobContainerClient container = client.GetBlobContainerClient("test");

        byte[] bytearray = new byte[2];
        bytearray[0] = 1;
        bytearray[1] = 2;
        
        BlobClient blob = container.GetBlobClient("testblob");

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytearray, false))
        {
            await blob.UploadAsync(ms);
        }


    }
}
```

[image]

Refer this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/) on blob storage in c#